# React Refresh Child Component from Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am trying to refresh a child component that is a data grid from a parent component that is set of search parameters.

```
return (
    <FormContainer title="Page Header2">
                <AppButton text={"ReloadTable"} type={"button"} **handleClick={() => {
                    tableRefresh = tableRefresh + 1;**
                }}></AppButton>

         
          <DataTable tableData={tableData} tableKeys={tableKeys2}
                    remote={true} remoteUrl="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" 
           **refresh={tableRefresh}** />
          
    </FormContainer>
```

DataTable is the child functional component that has a data grid, that loads only when the page is first loaded.
I placed a refresh property with an interger value tableRefresh that get incremented everytime i click the button, but the DataTable does not refresh at all.

Is there something i am missing?

Comment: Seems like you like to trigger an api call within the child component? Are you sure it's a functional component?

A better way is for the button to trigger an api request which then passes the data to the child.

Comment: can you include the DataTable component as well please?